# How can I get information about a caller of a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a function, `void funct (struct *B)`. It will be called by some instances of `struct A`. It only takes a pointer to strut B and modify that struct B instance. If struct A has `char *name`. My question is, can I get access to the `A_instance->name`? in the `funct`? If yes, how?
Thank you

Comment: structs cannot call anything. Please post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: What do you mean it's 'called by some instances?'

Comment: funct will e called in other functions

Comment: If it is called in other functions, what is the connection between struct A and struct B?

Comment: If it only takes a `struct B`, what are you doing trying to pass a `struct A` into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say this is C, which leaves out member functions (C does not have member functions, classes, etc). That means that funct is just a function (not a member of something) and that therefore, you only have the information that is passed in, and the globals. Since neither of those things contain what you want, you can't get it.

However, you also say that funct is called by 'some instances of struct A'. This doesn't make any sense, because in C structures don't have member functions, and thus can't make calls. Either you mean that operations on some instances of struct A are calling funct (in which case, my first answer applies), or you really are working with C++, and you've got member functions in struct A.

If funct is a member function of struct A, then funct has full access to all the members of the instance of A that called it, and can therefore check 'name' directly. Otherwise, we're back to my first answer.

In order to fix this, you're either going to need funct to be a member function of struct A (thereby going to C++), or you're going to need to pass the relevant information into funct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to write a function which needs to process a `name` value which is present in 2 different structures: `struct A` and `struct A`.  If that's the case then why not take a `char*` directly in funct and have callers pass the appropriate `name` field?

```
funct(char * name) { 
  ..
}

funct(aInstance->name);
funct(bInstance->name);
```

Comment: Why do you and others find it so necessary to jump in with assumptions, when waiting a bit could encourage the questioner to formulate his question more accurately, to the benefit of all?

Comment: the interface of funct is fixed. it only takes struct B*

Comment: @Neil, habbit.  I find giving a wrong answer is more likely to prompt a clarification for a question than commenting on the original question.  Take this example, OP commented a clarification ~3 minutes after my answer.

Comment: I find it unbelievable that you can suggest knowingly posting wrong answers.

Comment: @Neil, I don't knowingly post wrong answers. I post answers I reasonably believe to be true.  But it's possible the OP meant something differently than i read it.  The wrong answer at that point usually prompts a better question / clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid C doesn't permit you access to the calling functions data.  The easiest would be just to pass in a pointer to "struct A", at least then you'll always have access to A.

```
void func(struct B* b_ptr, struct A* a_ptr) 
{
    /* ... */
    /* do whatever you like with a_ptr->name */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a program like that:

```
struct B {
  int dummy;
}

struct A {
  char *name;
  struct B* b;
}

void funcA ( struct A* a ) {
   funcB ( a->b );
}

void funcB ( struct B* b ) {
   /* do something */
}
```

and you want to find out something about `a` in `funcB`, there is no proper way to do it. What you *might* try to do is, by using pointer arithmetic or negative array indices, to *guess* the location of `a` on the stack, which might even work with a given compiler on a given platform. If you make it work that way, please don't forget to post the solution to [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com).